# UITableView appearing before getting data from connectionDidFinishLoading

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode4.2

I have a situation where my table is loading before getting the data from my webservice.

When I debug it, I can see that my `NSMutableArray` has 123 objects, but it's not being reflected in the table.

This is my `connectionDidFinishLoading` method:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn{
myData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:xData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
SBJsonParser *jParser =  [SBJsonParser new];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *jsonObjects = [jParser objectWithString:myData error:&error];
NSMutableArray *books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSDictionary *dict in jsonObjects)
{
    Book *b = [Book new];
    b.bookName =[dict objectForKey:@"name"];
    b.published = [dict objectForKey:@"published"];
    [books addObject:b];

}
self.bookArray = books;
[self.tableView reloadData];
NSLog(@"myData = %@",myData);
}
```

If I debug this I'm getting my `jsonObjects` and populating my collection. But I notice my table is still empty.

Just to clarify this is my `tableView` method:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath{
...
Book *b = (Book *)[self.bookArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cell.textLabel.text = b.bookName;
....
```

Can anyone help me with what I'm missing?

Comment: Let's see the entire cellForRow method. Have you implemented rowsForSection?

Comment: @Dancreek I guess you meant numberOfRowsForSection? Anyway, that and [tableview reloadData] was my suspicion when I read the topic. He IS calling reloadData though, which eliminates the latter.

Comment: -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   
    return bookArray.count;
}

Comment: check that you don't have multiple table views. I've seen projects where the dev added a `UITableView` on top of the table view added automatically by `UITableViewController` so the table represented by `self.tableView` isn't visible.

Comment: but basically the self.tableView reloadData should just rebind the data to the table? on a side note, is there anyway to prevent the table from appearing until the data is completely finished? I was wondering how a activity indicator might assist in this situation. I do need to figure out why my table is empty though.

Comment: Why does `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` return bookArray.count? What about `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`? Maybe this last method could return bookArray.count value...**P.S. Make attention to memory leak!!**

Answer (score 1):

Check the calling thread. You cannot have UIKit updates on anything other than mainThread. I think your connectionDidFinishLoading: called on a seperate thread and that is the issue here.

Try

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider what is returned by numberOfRowsInSection (and numberOfSections) for the case where there is no data to show and for the case when there is data to show. Every time you call reloadData, the tableView will call these two methods to get the latest information about the data source. If your data has not loaded, then these delegate methods should report appropriate values. If the data is not loaded, you can test for a nil value or do some  similar test, and then return appropriate values. Once you data is loaded, the delegate methods should return values based on the size of the contents in the data source.

If you show us your code for these methods, someone can comment on whether this is your problem.

Comment: On your second question, you can just set the `hidden` propery of the tableView if you know the content is empty. You can do this inside one of the deleegate methods I mentioned. Remember to unhide it (hidden=NO) when there is content to show.

Comment: - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   
    return bookArray.count;
}
I dont have much in these methods.

Comment: I just debugged my program, and it calls the numberOfRowsInSection 1 time before my array is populated with data, and it's never called again.

Comment: Can you releasing or sending nil message to table view anywhere during this procees?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the way to do it is, **don't load the table till the contents get downloaded** via webservices.

For that don't set the delegates via IB. After the completion of this web request set the delegate and datasource via code and then call `reloadData` method.Hence we can make the table wait to load till the webcall get processed .Provide some neat activity indicator of custom HUD while data being loaded and that will do the job

Comment: Please add comments while downvoting

Comment: Setting the delegate is just fine. In the data source methods, he should take into account if the download has completed.

Comment: "he should take into account if the download has completed." Means?

Comment: @LeoNatan why call the delegates and all method when you know there is no value to load?

Comment: It means that if data is not ready, he should return 0 in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`. Once the connection finishes and the data is ready, he should pass a `reloadData` message to the table view, or even better, reload each cell individually for a nicer animation.

Comment: Only one data source method is called - `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` (possibly two with `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`). What is the problem exactly?

Comment: so how does it makes the answer wrong? tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: is an required method in delegate and it **should** be included,Otherwise warnings may point it out.What is wrong in setting the delegate and datasource via code? How come it become wrong?

Comment: Huh? He should implement that method regardless of the data being read or not. Your answer is not a good answer and creates unnecessary complication, which is why I downvoted.